# AS3 - Access variable named variableName[number]

Tags: actionscript-3, variables

I have 3 variables each named variable1, variable2, variable3.

I now have a for loop where i'd like to acces each variable one after the other.

```
for(var i:int = 1; i<4; i++){
    variable[i] = //whatever
}
```

how can i talk to the variables one after the other like above? which isnt correct. but, ya..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
for(var i:int = 1; i<4; i++){
    this["variable"+i] = //whatever
}
```